# Rails + Backbone Model is undefined even within fetch success

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm simply trying to `.get` an attribute and display it in an html element in a Rails, Backbone, Coffeescript app, yet the result is always `undefined` in the console.  The error with this code is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

The goal is to have one dashboard display various panels.  I've tried around 50 variations of the following code in the last 4 hours :\  Could you please help?

**Backbone Router:**

```
class App.Routers.Dashboard extends Backbone.Router

routes:
    '': 'index'

initialize: ->
    preflist = new App.Models.Preflist()
    preflist.fetch success: ->
        paneloneview = new App.Views.PanelOne(model: preflist)
        $('#panel-one').html(paneloneview.render().el)
```

**Backbone View:**

```
class App.Views.PanelOne extends Backbone.View

    template: JST['dashboard/panel_one']

    render: ->
        $(@el).html(@template(@model))
        this
```

**Template file:**

```
<h1>Panel One</h1>

<p><%= @model.length %></p>
```

Comment: Is that an Underscore template?

Comment: Hi, mu.  I'm using the backbone on rails gem which uses the eco templates.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to pass the render function an object (though that's just an educated guess).

Perhaps:

```
render: ->
  $(@el).html(@template({model: @model}))
  this

// and in an eco template

<h1>Panel 1</h1>
<p><%= @model.length %></p>
```

Comment: First, I really appreciate your help.  Thank you for your time.  I just tried this and it is still undefined.  Yet, the error is a bit different:  Uncaught ReferenceError: model is not defined

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I just had to sleep on it and then watch the Backbone RailsCast one more time. Thanks for your help everyone!  The correct code is this:

```
class App.Routers.Dashboard extends Backbone.Router

routes:
    '': 'index'

initialize: ->
    preflist = new App.Models.Preflist()
    preflist.fetch success: ->
        paneloneview = new App.Views.PanelOne(model: preflist)
        $('#panel-one').html(paneloneview.render().el)


class App.Views.PanelOne extends Backbone.View

    template: JST['dashboard/panel_one']

    render: ->
        $(@el).html(@template(preflist: @model))
        this



<h3>Panel One</h3>

<p><%= @preflist.get('panel_one') %></p>
```